# Why I can not do full screen

Tags: java, android, video, webview, web

No full screen button appears on webview while watching a video, what's the cause?

I will not go to these matters please help.

I am sorry for my English

MainActivity.java

```js
package net.aniplus.aniplus;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com");


        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Mobil Video İzle", "Bağlantınız Kontrol Ediliyor", true);
        progressDialog.show();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bir hata oluştur!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

```html
activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.aniplus.aniplus.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying for hours but I didn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

On android manifest change or add Activity's theme.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Hocam ben türküm nasıl yapabilceğimi biraz özetlermisiniz tema demişsiniz tam anlamadım ?

Comment: Manifest dosyasında main activity'yi bul oraya android:theme kodunu yapıştır. Uygulama full screen açılacaktır. Webviewda arayüz üzerinden sağa sola sabit görünüp görünmediğinden emin ol. Bir de relativelayout kullanma

Comment: Linearlayout daha çok işine yarar.

Comment: RelativeLayout kısımlarını Linerlayout yaptım en üstteki android:theme diye belirttiğiniz kodu AndroidManifest.xml dosyasındaki theme kısmıyla değiştirdim emülatör silinmiş indirip denicem sağolun yardımcı olduğunuz için.

Comment: Hocam dediklerinizi yaptım uygulama çöküyor açıldığı gibi

Comment: Hata kodu ne veriyor ? Hata ekranına baktığında ne diyor ?

Comment: Hocam herhangi bir hata vermiyor apk yı oluştururken uygulamayı telefonuma atıyorum orda kurup çalıştırıyorum açtığım gibi durduruldu hatası alıyorum aşşağıdaki linklerde kodlarım bulunmakta.                              http://i.hizliresim.com/3v3Oop.png                                                                       http://i.hizliresim.com/NldLEL.png                                                                       http://i.hizliresim.com/m4aXLZ.png

Comment: <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> activity tag'ı içerisine yazmalısın.

Comment: <activity> tag'ını yanlış yerde kapatmışsın. intent-filter activity tagı dışında kalmış sondaki /> sil

Comment: Öyle yapıncada 2 hata veriyor bu sefer http://i.hizliresim.com/qja5MW.png

Comment: activity altında activity açmışsın. birini sil theme'yi diğerine yapıştır. Kapatma tag'ına dikkat et

Comment: Kapanış activity sine yapıştırınca hata verdi resimdeki gibi  yerleştirdim hiçbir hata vermedi fakat uygulama yine hiçbir videoyu büyütme tuşu getirmiyor http://i.hizliresim.com/ZMa85V.png

Comment: Birader theme ifadesini activity tagı içinde yazmayı neden denemiyorsun ? Theme orada boş boş duruyor

Comment: Buyrun hocam yaptım dediğiniz gibi clean ettim sonra apk yada çevirdim ama uygulama çöküyor açıldığı gibi durduruldu hatası alıyorum ; http://i.hizliresim.com/3v3rR0.png bu arada kusura bakmayın sizi kızdırdıysam başınıza bela oldum cevap vermeyebilirsiniz hocam haklısınız bişey diyemem cahilliğime verin.